# 'to make use of' vs 'to base on'

Tags: difference

> Passage: All good history **should make fair use of its** sources, treating them with care and attention,
>   and not (for example) bending them out of shape to fit a preconceived idea.
>
> (d) An accurate history **needs to be based on** sources.

The answer is no. Despite the different wording, I think that they are the same. Basically, in the first sentence, doesn't 'treating them ... fit a preconceived idea' translate into 'accurate'? Also, aren't the bolded similar? For example, user Tyler James Young comments:

> “Good” ≠ “accurate”,  “make fair use of” ≠ “be based on”

1. Yet isn't 'accurate' good?
2. If a historian **makes fair use of** a writ, then the historian's use is **based on** the writ?

> the two are grammatically attached to different subjects, namely sources (in the passage) and a history (in the answer)

3. I don't understand this, because both sentences do feature 'history' as the subject?

Comment: "Based on sources" is a very, very poor, if not completely inaccurate paraphrase of "treat your sources in a good way". "You should treat you children well" does not mean "you should have children".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about text analysis and (basic) logic.

Comment: OP, I can see that you're making an effort to make your questions more suitable for ELL, but merely making the questions shorter doesn't actually do that. You'll need to ask a question that is actually on-topic here, for example by providing us your interpretation of the meaning of the passage, and then asking a question about why your perception is different to the one provided. Then it _might_ be on-topic.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to reword, but at the end of the day you aren't asking about a specific use of language, so it's hard to argue this would be helpful to other users. Your question is really about historiography, not English. That said, you can base an account on a source without being fair to it--by twisting its words or just being ignorant of what it really means--so the bolded sections aren't equivalent. And some accurate histories don't rely on written sources, e.g. de las Casas' accounts of Spain in the New World. Ultimately history has to be based on non-written sources!

Comment: P≈ In order for a history to be good, it should make fair use of its sources. Such sources should be treated with care and attention, not bent to fit.
(d)≈ In order to be accurate, a history must be based on sources.

The two are not equivalent. “Good” ≠ “accurate”, and “make fair use of” ≠ “be based on”. The two sentences are recipes for potentially different histories with different instructions and ingredients. Lastly: Not only does “treated. . .idea” not mean “accurate”, the two are grammatically attached to different subjects, namely sources (in the passage) and a history (in the answer).

Comment: The question may not have the broad appeal of "what verb tense do I use?", but I think helping non-native speakers comprehend English is within the spirit of ELL's mission even if it's not within the ["letter of the law"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/letter_1#letter_1__39). I think that questions that would be tolerated from other users are getting closed due to problems with this particular poster's previous questions and that's not entirely fair. There is a specific question here that can be resolved by looking at the sentence construction.

Comment: @ColleenV I think my reason for voting to close was that the second question appeared (and still appears) to have little to no effort put in. It's essentially crowd-sourcing general reference, and would be the equivalent of me asking something like "Twitter and Tumblr are the same thing, right?" on [webapps.se]. That's, unfortunately, the risk with asking multiple questions in one post.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung: Would you please simplify and explain 'the two are ... namely sources (in the passage) and a history (in the answer)'? I'm confused, because both sentences do feature 'history' as the subject? http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1212/8712

Comment: Making use of something is not the same as basing something on something. If I open a museum, the museum is based on my art work collection. Legally, I have to treat my employees at the museum well. I should make fair use of my employees (not mistreat them), but how does that ever, _ever_ mean that I should base my museum on employees?

Comment: In the answer, the descriptions associated with “history” are “accurate” and “based on sources”. In the passage, the descriptions associated with “history” are “good” and “makes fair use of sources”. In the passage, it is the _“sources”_ that are “treat[ed] with care, [etc.]”, so it doesn’t matter whether “treat[ed] with care, [etc.]” is equivalent to “accurate” because the former is how sources are treated and the latter is one way a history can end up. It may seem likely that treating sources with care will result in an accurate history, but neither sentence in itself makes that statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passage discusses how well the history uses the sources, so in that context it is possible to base your history on sources, but to distort their meaning so that the result is not accurate. The answer simply states that sources must be used and doesn't discuss **how** they are used, so it is not equivalent.